# How can I temporarily swap ports to launch with a custom URL, then swap ports back to original in asp.net MVC Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express, visual-studio-2017

I have 2 asp.net MVC Core Web projects in the same Visual Studio 2017 solution, and I need to launch them separately in a browser using my custom Launch URL. First, I added the following to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   myurl.mybiz.org
```

Initially, I set **Project1 > Properties > Debug > Launch URL:** to **https://myurl.mybiz.org** and left everything else alone. I was able to launch **Project1** at **https://myurl.mybiz.org** successfully in IE11.

Next, I wanted to launch **Project2** at **https://myurl.mybiz.org**, so I cut the Launch URL from **Project1** and pasted it to **Project2 > Properties > Debug > Launch URL:**. That did not work, I got a "This page can't be displayed" error.

So I swapped the localhost ports under **Web Server Settings > App URL:** between **Project1** and **Project2**. Originally, **Project1 > Properties > Debug > App URL:** was **http://localhost:12345/**, and **Project2 > Properties > Debug > App URL:** was **http://localhost:54321/**, so I set **Project1** to **54321** and **Project2** to **12345**, and this worked. I was able to launch **Project2** at **https://myurl.mybiz.org**.

When I was ready again to launch **Project1** at my custom url, I cut the **Launch URL: https://myurl.mybiz.org** out of **Project2** and pasted it back in **Project1**, and swapped the localhost ports back to their original numbers: **Project1 > Properties > Debug > App URL: http://localhost:12345/** and **Project2 > Properties > Debug > App URL: http://localhost:54321/**. But **Project1** will not launch at **https://myurl.mybiz.org**, I just get the error "This page can't be displayed." Afterward, when I switch everything back to how it worked when **Project2** successfully launched at my custom url, **Project2** still launches successfully at **https://myurl.mybiz.org**.

**Why won't Project1 launch at my custom url anymore after changing the settings this way?**

Here are my 2 launchSettings.json files after swapping back to run **Project1** at my custom launch url, after running **Project2** at the custom url (VS2017 indicates no change from original after swapping back to these settings):

**Project1:**

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12345/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://myurl.mybiz.org/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Project1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Project2:**

```
    {
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54321/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Project2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping ports then swapping back like this did not update the IIS Express applicationhost.config file, which prevented my site from launching at my custom url. Once I located applicationhost.config, I saw that the bindings were clearly wrong and needed to be updated.

This is what I needed it to be to get back to the original state:

```
<sites>
            . . . 
            <site name="Project1" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Repos\Projects\Project1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:myurl.mybiz.org" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12345:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <site name="Project2" id="3">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Repos\Projects\Project2" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54321:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            . . .
</sites>
```

But this is what the binding actually was before I manually fixed it:

```
<sites>
            . . .
            <site name="Project1" id="2">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Repos\Projects\Project2" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:myurl.mybiz.org" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54321:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            <site name="Project2" id="3">
                <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Repos\Projects\Project1" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:12345:localhost" />
                </bindings>
            </site>
            . . .
        </sites>
```